# Fields in Laravel Eloquent models

Tags: php, laravel, pdo, eloquent

I am new to Laravel and Eloquent, so excuse me if this is a totally stupid question.
I have been looking at how to create a model at both the documentation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) and also another tutorial [here](http://www.codeheaps.com/php-programming/creating-blog-using-laravel-4-part-1/) (in the Creating Models using Eloquent ORM section) and I've noticed that the actual fields of the table are never mentioned, unless there is something specific about them (like having a relationship with another table, or not requiring mass assignment, or if they need to be hidden from JSON output etc.)

Are these fields being omitted on purpose and PHP just adds them when it performs the query using PDO with `FETCH_OBJ` turned on?
If yes why is it that we do not explicitly put the fields in the model? Doesn't it help us to know what fields we have, and also IDEs such as PHPStorm to pop up the right auto-complete fields?

If they are actually required, what access level do they need to have?

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Column names (fields) are not required in Eloquent models. As you pointed out, it is only necessary to define the functions which determine the relationships that a model has with others.

It isn't necessary to include them, because of the reason you mentioned (Laravel does a `select *` and then adds all of the returned rows to the model object as public properties). This is a process dubbed hydration and you can see exactly what is happening by digging into the Laravel source. Here's a summary of what happens:

1. You call (for example), `Users::find(123);`
2. [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::find()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/64cf5b7807eb0a99377e3cf40d9b7ecf8cf705e0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L638-L645) calls [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::find()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/64cf5b7807eb0a99377e3cf40d9b7ecf8cf705e0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L73-L83)
3. `find()` constructs the `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 123` query and then returns the first result by calling [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::first()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/64cf5b7807eb0a99377e3cf40d9b7ecf8cf705e0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L123-L126)
4. `first()` adds `LIMIT 1` by calling [`Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::take()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/64cf5b7807eb0a99377e3cf40d9b7ecf8cf705e0/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1147-L1150)
5. Then `first()` sets the columns to be retrieved (`*` by default) by calling [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::get()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/64cf5b7807eb0a99377e3cf40d9b7ecf8cf705e0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L149-L162).
6. `get()` returns an [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/64cf5b7807eb0a99377e3cf40d9b7ecf8cf705e0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.php) by using the return value of [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::getModels()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/64cf5b7807eb0a99377e3cf40d9b7ecf8cf705e0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L406-L428)
7. `getModels()` actually performs the query and then calls [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::newFromBuilder()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/64cf5b7807eb0a99377e3cf40d9b7ecf8cf705e0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L459-L466) for each row returned
8. `newFromBuilder()` creates a new instance of the model and sets the columns (fields) by calling [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setRawAttributes()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/64cf5b7807eb0a99377e3cf40d9b7ecf8cf705e0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2687-L2692)

I've omitted some unrelated things such as eager loading to simplify the process, but this is basically what happens for each query.

You make a good point that knowing the fields beforehand can be helpful for autocompletion. <strike>Because of the nature of `setRawAttributes()` it is perfectly OK to declare all column names (fields) in your model (just make sure they are public). The convention, though (and for you sanity), is to omit them. Such declarations should be left to [migration files](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations).</strike>

After further examination of the source, it is **not** ok to declare the fields beforehand. This is because the actual attribute values are stored in an `$attributes` property and then accessed by the magic method `__get()`. The trouble here is that by defining the properties beforehand, you will prevent `__get()` from being called when you access the fields. Therefore, this is not an option.

However, there are [ways to hint to editors (like PhpStorm) about the existence of properties without explicitly defining them](http://laravel.io/forum/05-28-2014-using-phpstorm-with-laravel-confusedcom).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply. Pity I can't use it the same way of the PDO `fetchObject()` where I could specify the class name and it hydrates an instance of my specific class. I am in fact using PhpStorm, and it seems that the hints using the phpdoc tags work, so its a good workaround for proper IDE support.

Comment: If you really wanted that functionality, you could subclass the `Eloquent` class, which is actually `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`, (look in `app/config/app.php` for the aliases array and make sure to set the `Eloquent` alias to the proper FQN for your Eloquent subclass) and define `setRawAttributes()` to behave like that, but that would likely be more complicated that just using the phpdoc tags.

Comment: Yes, it will become overly complicated and beyond the scope of what I am trying to achieve. I just want to have things clean and maintainable. Deviating too much from the standard way might also put me in a situation where I wouldn't be able to look up solutions or ask questions here. The phpdoc tags seem fine, they're also useful to indicate which magic fields the model has if opening it through a less intelligent editor like Notepad++ or Vi. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: So how do I suppose to know the fields of a model?

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to make phpstorm to auto-complete column name and avoid warning.

```
/**
 * @property string $title Title of article
 */
class Article extends Eloquent
```